# Error: data helm repository doesn't work as expected

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am trying to deploy the helm charts from ACR using the terraform-provider-helm but it fails with below error. Can someone please let me know if I am doing anything wrong because I am not able to understand why is this searching for mcpshareddcr-index.yaml ?

Terraform Version
0.12.18

Affected Resource(s)
helm_release
helm_repository

Terraform Configuration Files

```
# Cluster RBAC helm Chart repository
data "helm_repository" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo" {
  name = "mcpshareddcr"
  url  = "https://mcpshareddcr.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo"
  username = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  password = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
}

# Deploy Cluster RBAC helm chart onto the cluster
resource "helm_release" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_release" {
  name  = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  repository = data.helm_repository.cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo.metadata[0].name
  chart = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  version = "0.1.0"
}
```

```
module usage:

provider "azurerm" {
  version                    = "=1.36.0"
  tenant_id                  = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
  subscription_id            = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  client_id                  = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret              = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = var.aks_cluster
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_aks
}

locals {
  kubeconfig_path = "/tmp/kubeconfig"
}

resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  filename = local.kubeconfig_path
  content  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config_raw
}

provider "helm" {
  home = "./.helm"
  kubernetes {
    load_config_file = true
    config_path = local.kubeconfig_path
  }
}

// Module to deploy Stratus offered helmcharts in AKS cluster
module "mcp_resources" {
  source = "modules\/helm\/mcp-resources"
  ARM_CLIENT_ID = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  ARM_TENANT_ID = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
```

Expected Behavior
Deploy of helm charts on AKS fetching from ACR.

Actual Behavior
Error: Looks like "***/helm/v1/repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: open .helm/repository/cache/.helm/repository/cache/mcpshareddcr-index.yaml: no such file or directory

Steps to Reproduce
terraform plan

Comment: What is your helm version?

Comment: @Blokje5  its 3.0.0

Comment: Do you check if you use the right chart name that stored in your ACR?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes indeed it looks correct
  mcp-tf-aks-resources git:(master) ✗ helm fetch mcpshareddcr/mcp-rbac-cluster
➜  mcp-tf-aks-resources git:(master) ✗ ls  
README.md                  mcp-rbac-cluster-0.1.0.tgz

Comment: It seems you just download the chart, do you store the chart into ACR? As it showed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos)?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes its stored in ACR with another pipeline and then i download the same chart on local and send the output. I don't know the way to see the helm charts directly from azure portal as we can see the images (if you know that please let me know) and that is why I add the repo locally and see if the helm charts are there or not.
```
   - task: AzureCLI@1
              inlineScript: |
                az acr helm push -n ${{ parameters.registryNameDev }} $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.helmChartPath }}-${{ parameters.helmChartVersion }}.tgz
```

Comment: Yeah, you can use the CLI command `az acr hem list -g group -n acr -o table` to see the chart that stored in the ACR.

Comment: @CharlesXu : Thanks so i see the helm charts but why the terraform-provider-helm isn't working even if the chart name is correct and its present

NAME                CHART VERSION    APP VERSION    DESCRIPTION
------------------  ---------------  -------------  ------------------------------------------------------------
mcp-rbac-cluster    0.1.0            1.16.0         A Helm chart for Kubernetes

Comment: Can you provide a link to download the chart? Maybe I can take a test for you.

Comment: @CharlesXu may be you won't be able to download because its in our organization. its a simple chart in ACR which I am trying to deploy on AKS cluster using the terraform-provider-helm version 3 plugin

Comment: @CharlesXu any suggestion please ?

Comment: This issue is resolved now vsts creates its own directories so i had to update the helm home in terraform-provider-helm to that
HELM_PLUGINS="/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.local/share/helm/plugins" 

HELM_REGISTRY_CONFIG="/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.config/helm/registry.json" 

HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE="/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/helm/repository" 

HELM_REPOSITORY_CONFIG="/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.config/helm/repositories.yaml" 

HELM_NAMESPACE="default" 

HELM_KUBECONTEXT="" 

HELM_BIN="helm" 

HELM_DEBUG="false"
home to :/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.config/helm/repository

Comment: I think it's not dependent on the ACR, it's DevOps. Well, then you can add an answer to display the solution or you can accept my answer if I add it for you.

Comment: Can you explain the variables you set? I'm a bit confused on them.